# weighted average of tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a custom objective function in keras frame.
Respectively a weighted average function that takes the two arguments tensors y_true and y_pred ; the weights information is derived from y_true tensor.

Is there a weighted average function in tensorflow ?
Or any other suggestions on how to implement this kind of loss function ?

My function would look something like this:

function(y_true,y_pred)
  A=(y_true-y_pred)**2
  w - derivable from y_true, tensor of same shape as y_true
  return average(A, weights=w) <-- a scalar

y_true and y_pred are 3D tensors.

Comment: here a simple way to operate a learnable weighted average: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595660/weighted-average-custom-layer-weights-dont-change-in-tensorflow-2-2-0/62595957#62595957

Answer (score 1):

you can use one of the existing objectives (also called loss) on `keras` from [here](https://keras.io/objectives/#usage-of-objectives).

you may also implement your own custom function loss:

```
from keras import backend as K

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)

# Let's train the model using RMSprop
model.compile(loss=my_loss, optimizer='SGD', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

notice the `K` module, its the keras backend you should use to fully utilize keras performance, dont do something like this unless you dont care from performance issues:

```
def my_bad_and_slow_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return sum((y_pred - y_true) ** 2, axis=-1)
```

for your specific case, please write your desired objective function if you need help to write it.

## Update

you can try this to provide weights - `W` as loss function:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    W = np.arange(9) / 9.  # some example W
    return K.mean(K.pow(y_true - y_pred, 2) * W)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The mean_squared_error would do just fine, except i need to apply weights for each entry. The task at hand is semantic segmentation via cnn (encoding-decoding architecture) ; two classes, heavily unbalanced. I know about weight class or sample weights in keras, but the ratio between classes is variable from image to image. This is why i am considering building the weights tensor to apply coefficients for each pixel accordingly.

Comment: updated example for your case. if need more help please post the exact calculation you try to create.